# How do I remove an element from a user created list (shopping cart)

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, shopping-cart, removechild

```
const cartContent = document.querySelector(".cart_content");
.
.
.
addCartItem(item) {
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('cart_item');
div.innerHTML = `
    <div class="shop_cart_items_wrapper">
        <span class="remove_item" data-id=${item.id}><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
    <div class="shop_cart_items">
        <p class="item_amount">${item.amount}</p>
        <span class="cart_title_text_wrapper"><h4 class="cart_title_text">${item.title}</h4></span>  
        <span class="cart_price_amount_wrapper"><h5 class="cart_price_amount">$${item.price}</h5></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="inc_dec_amounts_cart">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-up" data-id=${item.id}></i>
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-down" data-id=${item.id}></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`;
            cartContent.appendChild(div);
}
.
.
.
cartContent.addEventListener("click", event => {
       if (event.target.classList.contains("remove_item")) {
        let removeItem = event.target;
        let id = removeItem.dataset.id;
        cartContent.removeChild.firstElementChild(removeItem.parentElement.parentElement);
        this.removeItem(id);
       }
```

So I have everything that's needed for the code to work. I want the entire product item removed from the cart as I press the 'times' icon. I think the `removeItem.parentElement.parentElement` is not targetting the times icon. What do I have to do to make it target the times icon and close the `cart_item` div?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to remove the item relative to where the class `remove_item` is defined (which I assume is maybe the X icon or something. A better way of going about is just defining an id on the parent item itself, finding that element via `document.querySelector`, and then removing it.

So instead of having something like this

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('cart_item');
div.setAttribute('data-item-id', item.id); // <-- now the cart_item has an id associated to it
div.innerHTML = `
    <div class="shop_cart_items_wrapper">
        <span class="remove_item" data-id=${item.id}><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
    <div class="shop_cart_items">
```

And then your remove function becomes

```
cartContent.addEventListener("click", event => {
       if (event.target.classList.contains("remove_item")) {
        let removeItem = event.target;
        let id = removeItem.dataset.id;
        cartContent.removeChild(document.querySelector(`[data-item-id=${id}`));
        this.removeItem(id);
       }
```

Or something of the sort. If you're looking for a specific answer on how to get this relatively via your method, that's possible but just giving you another way of going about the solution.